# Is it possible to get the pixels coordinates of the detected object with Detectron2?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, detectron

Is there any way to save segmentation area to a TXT file or CSV file?

I would like to get all the pixel coordinates (integers) of segmentation area, but I don't know how to do it.
Is there any way to do it?
thank you in advance